# Handle with ajax request after click link

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have link in my page

```
<a href="tel:+1111" id="tel">+1111</a>
```

i want to save every click in database

i made this ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#tel').on('click', function() {
            var location = $(this).attr('href');
            var action = 'script.php';

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: action,
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location = location;
                },
                error: function(data){
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

now what must i do, what is the code i have to put in script.php

Comment: Are you going to send any data to server? For example, location or something? Right now, you are sending empty string.

Comment: no , i dont want to send any data

Comment: You can put that code directly in `script.php`, just make sure it is not inside of a `<?php` tag.

Comment: i just want to add new row to my table in database

Comment: Do you have a database? Can we take a look at the table columns.

Comment: what is the code i will put it ?

Comment: yes i want to save every click in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need send some data to script.php, for example

```
url: action,
data: {location: location},
dataType: 'json',
```

next in script.php you can read this data

```
$_POST['location']
```

create sql query and save data in DB.

Answer (score 0):

send `href` as json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#tel').on('click', function() {
            var location = $(this).attr('href');
            var action = 'script.php';

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: action,
                data: {"href":location}, // this line update
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data['state]); // this line add for debug server side
                    window.location = location;
                },
                error: function(data){
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and update `script.php` like below:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['href']){
        //connect to database
        //update table
        echo json_encode(array('state'=>'ok'));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('state'=>'error'));
    } ?>
```